# How to invoke a custom code generating target before a VC++ project is compiled with VS 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with C# and C++ projects. Visual Studio 2019 is what is being used to build. I have a target that generates a .h file which affects all the native projects (i.e. C++ projects).
I like this target be invoked before compiling any C++ code.

How do I do it?

I added a property like below and rebuilt the C++ project. I don't see MyGenFiles getting invoked.

**`<BeforeClCompileTargets>$(BeforeClCompileTargets);MyGenFiles</BeforeClCompileTargets>`**

**Update**
Above is the right approach to get this done. It happened to be my verifications that was the problem. I added a message task as Jonathan suggested, I could see the target getting invoked.

Comment: Just configure a project dependeny on the solution (right click the Solution->Project Dependencies)

Comment: How are you determining that `MyGenFiles` is not invoked? If you add a `Message` task in the `MyGenFiles` target, is the `Message` task invoked Because you are generating a source file it would probably be more correct to add your Target to `BuildGenerateSourcesTargets` (but I don't think that is the issue with the target appearing not be invoked).

Comment: The target generates a file if the target file is going to be different from current state with writelinestofile task. I was looking for a string "Target MyGenFiles" in output tab. For some reason it wasn't printing it even though it is invoking the target. Anyway the message task confirmed it is being invoked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: For most levels of verbosity, MSBuild logs the target name only when there is log output from the target. (I think only `/v:diag` may show every target that is invoked.)